# I have a joint PMF in matrix form. How to use R to find $P(N > G)$?

Tags: r, probability

I've just started learning R, and I'm attempting to do some calculations involving a joint PMF in R.

The following matrix holds the joint PMF $p_{NG}(n,g)$:

```
(pNG <- matrix(c(16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 
                 0, 0, 2, 6, 6, 2, 0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/80, 
               ncol = 5, nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE))

colnames(pNG) <- rownames(pNG) <- 0:4
```

The marginal PMFs of $N$ and $G$ are found as follows:

```
(pN <- rowSums(pNG))
(pG <- colSums(pNG))
```

The expected value and variance of $N$ are found as follows:

```
(EN <- sum(0:4 * pN))
(VarN <- sum((0:4 - EN)^2 * pN))
```

The conditional PMF of $N$ at $G = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ are found as follows:

```
(pNgG <- sweep(pNG, 2, pG, "/"))
```

The expected value of $N$ given $G$ are found as follows:

```
(ENgG <- colSums(0:4 * pNgG))
```

The variance of $N$ given $G$ is found as follows:

```
(VarNgG <- colSums(outer(0:4, ENgG, "-")^2 * pNgG))
```

With all this said and done, I want to find $P(N > G)$. However, I'm unsure of how to do this. I was thinking that there is a pattern here that has to do with the diagonals (upper or lower) of the matrix, since this is where $i > j$ or $j > i$; on the diagonals, we have $i = j$..

Comment: You can use `upper.tri()` and `lower.tri()` to get the upper and lower triangular submatrices. Since this is square, I think something like `sum(pNG[lower.tri(pNG)])` is what you want.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, Gregor! So `sum(pXY[lower.tri(pXY)])` is P(N > G), if I'm not mistaken, and 1 - `sum(pXY[lower.tri(pXY)]) = P(G > N)?

Comment: For the first part, sure -- I wasn't super clear on which margin I was going over. For the second part, no. `1 - ...` will be `P(G >= N)` (>=, not >), because it includes the diagonal where they are equal. Replacing `lower.tri` with `upper.tri` will give you `P(G > N)`, which, for your matrix, looks to be 0.

Comment: Double check what I've said with your understanding of which one's N and which one's G. I might have them switched.

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I think that's all correct. Thanks again, Gregor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to add up all the cells of the matrix where the row number is greater than the column number. This is the "lower triangular" sub-matrix, which you can access using R's `lower.tri()` function:

```
sum(pXY[lower.tri(pXY)])
```

You can use `upper.tri()` for the opposite. (And `diag()` if you need the diagonal, where the row number equals the column number.)